How to fix repeating already showed elements from the array?
I am making blackjack game and encoutering some problems which i get no idea to solve them.
When i click button to add a new card, instead of just pushing new card (number) into the array of the first 2 cards, it is added and then again displayed the same array but with added new card.
It looks like this

but it need to like this

Second problem is also when i add cards variables into the function which is connected to the button for starting the game. Whenever i click to pull up for the new card button it transform card 1 and card 2 into another cards instead of keeping them as they were (they have been overwritten with 2 new random numbers.)
allCards = []
sumCards = 0



function randomCard() {
    let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13) + 1
    if (randomNumber === 1) {   
        return 11
    }

    else if (randomNumber > 10) {
        return 10
    }

    else return randomNumber
    

    
}


  ##This is the main function
function resetCard() {
    receivedCards()
}

function receivedCards() {  

    let card1 = randomCard()
    let card2 = randomCard()

    let sveKarte = [card1, card2]
    console.log(allCards)
    sumCards = card1 + card2

    

    for (let i = 0; i < allCards.length; i+=1) { 
        cardsHtml.innerText +=  " " + allCards[i] 
    }

    sum.innerHTML = "Sum: " + (sumCards)


###This is co-main function
function newCard() {
    
    
    let newCard = randomCard()

    if (sumCards <21) {
        allCards.push(newCard)
        sumCards += newCard
    }

    else if (sumCards>=21) {
        button2.style.display = "none"
    }

    resetCard()    ///this is function for starting/restarting the game                             
}


I tried adding splice function,
for (let i = 0; i < allCards.length; i+=1) { 
  cardsHtml.innerText +=  " " + allCards[i] 
  sveKarte.splice(i, 1)
} 

When i add it, it doesn't show multiple same numbers, but it adding up one card instead of two.
///HTML
<body>
    <h1>BlackJack</h1>
    

    <p>Do you want to pull new card  ?</p>
    <button id="kreni" onclick="receivedCards">TRY</button>
    <br>
    <br>

    <button id="Pkreni" onclick="newCard()">PULL UP MORE</button>


    <script src="index1.js"></script>
<body>```


Don't splice in the loop. Before the loop, clear the output with cardsHtml.innerText = "";

But please provide enough code for us to reproduce the problem. Currently you have only provided functions, but you have not included the calls to (one of) these functions.

You are calling resetCard() in newCard, that's why the next card overwrites the existing cards. I would rename the functions to more self-descritious names not to think more when I'm looking to the code. "receivedCards" would be "startNewGame", "newCard" would be "pullNewCard", etc.  https://javascript.info/function-basics#function-naming - a good post for choosing the names for the functions

I tried running code without resetCard() in newCard, but then newCard function doesn't work.

I edited code, and i tried using splice, the game then just doesn't want to start and after using cards. Tried to remove cardsHTML text but if i set cardsHtml.innertext  = " " in function it is showing 1 number per pulling and if i set it before for function, it shows 2 numbers.

Easiest way is to have a list of things like ['AD','2D'..'KD','AS'...'AH','AC'...]. they will always be in a fixed index positions 0-51 (or 1-52 depending on language.. To implement shuffle, have a second list of 0-51 that you randomise - then use that to indirectly address cards.

Well i succeeded to fix problem with repeating numbers that already printed to the html, i added sveKarte.splice(0, 2) in newCard but also moved newCard to the another array and just did sum of the arrays of allCards and newCard. But for some reason it works only if i  move variables of card1, card 2, sumcard and allcards out of the recieviedCards() function.
